# Property must be initialized or be abstract

Tags: android, kotlin

How to declare class field? Like we can have it in java:

```
protected SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
```

And later in `onCreate()`:

```
mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
```

Now I can use it anywhere I want (in subclasses of this base activity).

I try to do same in Kotlin:

```
protected var sharedPreferences : SharedPreferences
```

And in `onCreate()`:

```
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
```

But I get a warning: "Property must be initialized or be abstract"

Answer (score 214, accepted):

If you'd like to initialize a property outside the constructor, then [late-initialized properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties) is what you may be looking for. Declare the property with the `lateinit` modifier, which will allow to skip the otherwise required initializer and will make the property access fail with exception until some meaningful value is assigned to it:

```
protected lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
```

Comment: I tried to use "protected var sharedPreferences : SharedPreferences? = null" and it also works, what's the difference?

Comment: I see that if I use Dagger2 for DI, I have to use your variant, right?

Comment: The difference is that you can declare non-nullable values with lateinit.

Answer (score 21):

Pulling this out of the comments from Alexander Udalov's answer for visibility. 
For nullable properties:

`protected var sharedPreferences : SharedPreferences? = null`

...and assign it a value later.