# lateinit modifier is not allowed on primitive type properties in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am defining like a instance variable in `kotlin` and want to initialize it `onCreate` method of an `activity`.

```
var count: Int
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    count.inc()
}
```

Here I am getting a below error on count variable.

> Property must be initialized or be abstract in Kotlin

Well, I read this thread [Property must be initialized or be abstract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849811/property-must-be-initialized-or-be-abstract) and tried same but again I am getting a below error.

> lateinit modifier is not allowed on primitive type properties

```
lateinit var count: Int
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    count.inc()
}
```

Is there any way to do this in `Kotlin` ?

Comment: see:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44206094/3679676

Answer (score 88, accepted):

There are several ways to resolve this issue.

You can Initialise it with default value (e.i `0` or `-1` or whatever) and then initialise it whenever your logic says.

Or tell compiler that count will be initialised later in this code by using `Delegates.notNull` check [notNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/not-null.html).

```
var count: Int by Delegates.notNull<Int>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // You can not call `Int.inc()` in onCreate()` function until `count` is initialised.
    // count.inc()
    // **initialise count** 
}
```

And if you need count value on demand (if not necessary to initialise in `onCreate`), you can use `lazy` function. Use this only if you have an intensive (Some calculation/Inflating a layout etc) task that you want to do `on demand`, Not to just assign a value.

```
var count:Int by lazy {
    // initialise
}
```

Now you can decide what to use.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Cool, `var count: Int by Delegates.notNull<Int>()` solves the problem of having `@ ConfigurationProperties` class in Spring that gets primitive values from properties file, without necessity to provide static default value.

Comment: What solution do you see when you need to check whether it was initialized already. With `lateinit` you could do `::count.isInitialized`. With `Delegates.notNull` you would have to catch the exception which is bad. Is there another way including checking for initialization?

Comment: @Vampire If you think there are cases where `count` could be uninitialized then make it nullable. If there is a guarantee that `count` will be initialized before its uses then only use `lateinit`. For example, initializing it in constructor will make sure of its initialization.

Comment: What is the speciality of lazy function ?

Comment: Thank goodness Kotlin has rescued us from the complexity of the Java programming language.

Answer (score -21):

There's no reason to leave it uninitialized. Just initialize it to 0 or -1.

`lateinit` is for non-null object references that can't easily be initialized in the class body definition.

Comment: Especially with the release of Kotlin 1.2 and the introduction of `isInitialized` it makes a lot of sense to leave a property uninitialized - and maybe 0 and -1 are both legal values after the initialization?