# Using lateinit primitives wrappers

Tags: kotlin

I've got something like that:

```
@LocalServerPort
private lateinit var serverPort: Integer
```

And IDEA warns that `java.lang.Integer` should not be used, use `kotlin.Int` instead. But `kotlin.Int` cannot be used with a `lateinit` property. Is there a way to satisfy both restrictions?

Update: I'm compiling with `-Werror`, as I think every project should. Therefore, code becomes ridden with `@Suppress("PLATFORM_CLASS_MAPPED_TO_KOTLIN")` adding unnecessary garbage.

Comment: Just for the record, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38769161/4465208) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44386513/4465208) are some previous times this has been brought up. Not necessarily a duplicate, because we still don't really have an explanation for why a boxed Integer couldn't be used.

Comment: @zsmb13 Saw those, thanks. Lack of an explanation is what led to this question.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of explanation you're looking for. As the documentation says, `lateinit` is currently not supported for primitive types. It is possible to change the design of `lateinit` and add support for primitive types, in one way or another, but as of Kotlin 1.2 this change has not been made. Your code is one possible workaround for the lack of support.

Comment: @yole that's explanation enough, thanks. On a sidenote, in that case, IDEA should stop saying that Integer shouldn't be used for lateinits, as that seems to be the most natural workaround for an essential use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is, Delegates.

```
@LocalServerPort
private var serverPort by Delegates.notNull<Int>()
```

Delegates are computationally slightly more expensive than `lateinit`. I use `lateinit` where I can, otherwise I use the method above. The code above will present exactly the same as `lateinit` ie. no null check needed.

Comment: Still doesn't compile: `@LocalServerPort` -- `Error:(21, 5) Kotlin: This annotation is not applicable to target 'member property with delegate'`

Comment: Then use `@get:LocalServerPort`

Comment: You're right, through it was `@set:` that made it work.