# Why can't I set lateinit for a int var in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I hope to initial the private a var id later, so I use the code  `private lateinit var id:Int`

But I get the error *'lateinit' modifier is not allowed on properties of primitive type*, why? How can I fix it? Thanks!

**Code A**

```
class UIAddEditBackup: AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mContext: Context //OK
    private var isAdd: Boolean=false //OK
    private lateinit var id:Int   // I get the error

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_add_edit_backup)
        id=5
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811421/using-lateinit-primitives-wrappers

Comment: This post also gives good explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38769161/535761

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Normally, properties declared as having a non-null type must be
>   initialized in the constructor. However, fairly often this is not
>   convenient. For example, properties can be initialized through
>   dependency injection, or in the setup method of a unit test. In this
>   case, you cannot supply a non-null initializer in the constructor, but
>   you still want to avoid null checks when referencing the property
>   inside the body of a class.

With primite types you can just remove the `lateinit` modifier and initialize with zero (or false for booleans)