# Manipulate navigation graph arguments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I use the Android navigation graph and I send arguments. Below is how I fetch those arguments:

```
val args: MyFragmentArgs by navArgs()
```

Spontaneously I did:

```
var args: MyFragmentArgs? by navArgs()
```

and after I had used them, I set them to null:

```
override fun onStart() { // Need to do this in onStart
    useMyArgsOnFirstTimeOpen(args.myObject)
    args = null
}
```

This obviously do not work and I get: 'Missing setValue method on delegate of type NavArgsLazy'

I wanted to do this to make sure that those arguments only get used the first time the fragment is opened. And not after it has been killed and restarted.

Can I do something clever with the navArgs, alter it, or wrap it somehow to let me achieve the effect I want?

```
// want to enable either of these
args = null
args.myObject = null
```

Below is the code for navArgs()

```
@MainThread
inline fun <reified Args : NavArgs> Fragment.navArgs() = NavArgsLazy(Args::class) {
    arguments ?: throw IllegalStateException("Fragment $this has null arguments")
}
```

Or is the solution: Change the object passed in the args to a class that supports clearing it? ie:

```
args.myObject.clear() // wish to avoid this
```

Comment: You don't need to clear them. But you might want to consider using SavedStateHandle with the fragment args passed in as the initial values.

Comment: @Adam, did you figure out how to do it?

Comment: @makkhaygurung If i remember correctly I went with a variant of what I wanted to avoid. `args.myObject.clear()`

Comment: @Adam, that is interesting. How do I make it support clearable?

Comment: This was long ago and i don't quite remember the context of this. But putting your argument in an e.g. mutableList, should work. Then after you have used it you can clear the list.

Comment: there should be no reason to manually clear args.

Answer (score 2):

clearing arguments doest work, you can change or manipulate args of navGraph by doing this :

```
lateinit var navArgs: XFragmentArgs
```

then override onAttach method to create navArgs instead of using lazy func:

```
    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        navArgs = 

MovieDetailRecyclerListFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments())
            super.onAttach(context)
        }
```

then you can use your navArgs as usual and change one of its arguments :

```
//check your arguments
if(navArgs.X){
//change the argument that you want to manipulate

navArgs = MovieDetailRecyclerListFragmentArgs.Builder(navArgs).setX("your value).build()
}
```

by this way you can change the value of your parameters in arguments or even clear it.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any way to manipulate the `navArgs` generated by the navigation compoents. While they are using `arguments` to get the navigation arguments defined in the navigatino graph, the library is keeping a cached version of each argument and restores this value. So `arguments.clear()` does not affect the arguments produced by `navArgs()`.

So in the case that you need to consume a navigation argument only once, I guess for now we'll have to do that manually:

```
        val navArg = arguments?.get("homePage")
        if (navArg != null && navArg is HomePage) {
            doSomethingOnlyOnce(navArg)
            arguments?.clear()   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
lateinit var args: MyFragmentArgs by navArgs()
```

Then initialise your variable

```
override fun onStart() { // Need to do this in onStart
  args = null
  useMyArgsOnFirstTimeOpen(args.myObject)
}
```

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to compile for me: 'lateinit modifier is not allowed on delegated properties'

Comment: B'coz you are using primitive types.
Follow link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381791/lateinit-modifier-is-not-allowed-on-primitive-type-properties-in-kotlin

Comment: This cannot work for several reasons: 1. `by navArgs()` cannot return a `var`. It only returns  `val`. 2. Since `args` is always immutable, you cannot set it to null. 3. Even if this was possible, setting it to null before reading `args.myObjects` would not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

try navArgs.toBundle().clear()

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this in Kotlin:

```
requireArguments().apply {
    getString(someKey)?.also { argument ->
        // do something with the argument
        doSomething(argument)

        // override it
        putString("argument", defaultValue)
    }
}
```