# Int -> Property must be initialized or be abstract

Tags: android, kotlin

Android Studio 3.6

In Kotlin I try this:

```
private var tableNumber: Int
```

but get compile error:

```
Property must be initialized or be abstract
```

this property I will init later. I can't use `lateinit` because I get another error:

```
'lateinit' modifier is not allowed on properties of primitive types
```

Comment: The error says all the information you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [lateinit modifier is not allowed on primitive type properties in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381791/lateinit-modifier-is-not-allowed-on-primitive-type-properties-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 3):

Either you have to initialize it directly like:

```
private var tableNumber: Int = 0
```

or if you want to be able to check if the value has been set or not, you could make it optional (still need to initialize it tho):

```
private var tableNumber: Int? = null
```

Making it abstract makes not sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have to either initialize the property with a default value, like

```
private var tableNumber: Int = 0
```

or make it abstract

```
private abstract var tableNumber: Int
```

Those are different things, so think about what to choose here…